# RegEx - JavaScript - match word and not match another word

Tags: javascript, regex

I use regex to match any string contains certain word (e.g: 'dark')

```
     if (features[i].attributes.color.match(new RegExp(dark, "ig")) ) )
..
..
```

How can I modify it to match any string contains 'dark; but NOT contains 'blue' ?
I tried:

```
if(
features[i].attributes.color.match(new RegExp(dark, "ig")) ) && !features[i].attributes.color.match(new RegExp(blue, "ig")) )
}
..
..
```

with no luck

Comment: Why don't you just use `.indexOf()`?

Comment: What's `dark`? If it's not a variable containing a string then it should be a string...

Comment: It would be nice if you you cleaned up the formatting and gave the actual string you were trying to match as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(features[i].attributes.color.indexOf("dark") != -1 && features[i].attributes.color.indexOf("blue") == -1){
// found dark, didn't find blue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex for "contains dark and not blue":

```
/^(?!.*\bblue\b)(?=.*\bdark\b).*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as following:

```
new RegExp(/dark/)
```

U can use

```
.indexOf("dark")
```

If you use jquery then

```
.contains("dark")
```

Comment: Doesn't `RegExp` take a string?

Comment: i didnot give a string there. Its a pattern.

Comment: Ah, it takes patterns too. But but why use the constructor and not simply `/dark/`? I usually use `RegExp` with a string otherwise what's the reason? Also I'm pretty sure `contains()` in jQuery is for DOM elements, for text you have to use the `:contains` pseudo selector, or `filter` the collection and test the text of each element.

Comment: Relevant docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/, http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/